How to inject dependencies
I am trying to inject GoogleSignIn but when building throws exception error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method .
this is my file
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped
    fun providesGoogleSignInOptions(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
        GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped
    fun providesGoogleSignInClient(gso: GoogleSignInOptions,@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
        GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso)
}

I don't know what happened or how to deal with it
I tried searching for something similar but couldn't find it, it took me almost a day to find the problem but it didn't seem to work.

This module looks fine and should work if you inject GoogleSignIn in a view model. However, if you try to use it to inject in an activity, it will show the error you mentioned. If this is the case, you could install the module in ActivityComponent or SingletonComponent and scope the bindings with @ActivityScoped or @Singleton respectively, according to Component hierarchy.
